# Stream de audio no android studio

Tags: android

Estou usando o seguinte código para reproduzir um som salvo na nuvem

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/vozes-leagueof-legends.appspot.com/o/Aatrox%2Fataque2.mp3?alt=media&token=b523f118-126d-428d-856d-461c0c2e9686"), "audio/mp3");
startActivity(intent);
```

Porém ele reproduz o audio no Play Music , e eu queria que ele reproduzisse no prprio app , alguém tem uma dica de como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa criar um **MediaPlayer** pra reproduzi-lo no próprio app.

Por exemplo:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
try {
     mp.setDataSource("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/vozes-leagueof-legends.appspot.com/o/Aatrox%2Fataque2.mp3?alt=media&token=b523f118-126d-428d-856d-461c0c2e9686");
     mp.prepare();
     mp.start();
} catch (IOException e) {
     Log.e("Log", "prepare() failed");
}
```

Depois você pode incluir outras opções, como pause, stop e controle de volume.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/volume-and-earphones.html